# Getting all the possible distances between points

Tags: c#, math, combinations, pseudocode

I have created a program to spawn a number of points (the number is given by the user).

Therefore the program spawns N points
*see the image for an example, it has 3 points in that case* [image]

What I need is to get all the possible distances between those villages (In the example it's distance: AB, AC, BC).

The points are stored in a single array (that scores x-coordinate and y-coordinate)

```
List<Villages>
```

I know that I new Pythagoras Theorem, I just cannot get the foreach loop right.

Comment: You should show us your attempt at the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 2):

I would think you would want a regular nested **for-loop** rather than foreach.

Something like this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < villageList.Count; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < villageList.Count; ++j)
    {
        distanceFunc(villageList[i], villagelist[j]);
    }
}
```

Where *distanceFunc* is whatever implementation of a distance function you want to use and *villageList* is your `List` of villages.

The reason you would use for-loops is because you need the inner loop to start one element past the the outer loop (i + 1), and foreach loops don't let you easily access the index you're currently at (they let you access the element itself, but not easily see it's position in the array).

Answer (score 1):

You need two `for` loops:

```
var villages = new List<Villages>() { ... };
for (int i = 0; i < villages.Count - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < villages.Count; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(getDistance(villages[i], villages[j]));
```

Where `getDistance` you should write yourself. It should return a distance between two specified `Village`s.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this pseudocode:

```
villages = [a, b, c, ...]
for i=0 to len(villages)-2:
    for j=i+1 to len(villages)-1:
        print(villages[i], villages[j], dist(villages[i], villages[j]))
```